# How to return string value?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, ytdl

I wrote this code

```
const link = "CKV0nSlxV8M"


const rendertest = async (link) => {
    const format = await ytdl(link, { quality: '22'})
    let test = JSON.stringify(format[0].url) 
        alert(test)  //string type
    return test
  
}

let finalValue = rendertest(link)
    
    
console.log(finalValue)
```

And I got this value from the `test` (string)

[image]

but exam value is not a `String` (Object)

[image]

I don't know which part I wrote wrong. I want the output of the same `test` and `finalValue`

Comment: `rendertest` is an `async` function, you are not awaiting it here: `let finalValue = rendertest(link)` so the `finalValue` "[object Object]" logged is the `Promise`.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know the exact cause! @DrewReese

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you define a function as `async`, behind the scenes it returns a promise. So, you have to wait for the promise to fulfill. Try this:

```
const link = "CKV0nSlxV8M"


const rendertest = async (link) => {
    const format = await ytdl(link, { quality: '22'});
    const test = JSON.stringify(format[0].url);

    return test
}

rendertest(link).then(finalValue => {
  console.log(finalValue)
}
```

Comment: I tried this code but gave me [',' expected] error
I've been search for then() and this seems to be what I need to use like promise()

Thanks for help!

Comment: What do you mean? This code is valid. Anyway, your welcome :)